# solving a two dimensional stochastic differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

This is exercise 5.8 from SDE by Oksendal.

Solve the two dimensional SDE:

$dX_1(t)=X_2(t)dt + \alpha  dB_1(t)$

$dX_2(t)= -X_1(t)dt + \beta dB_2(t)$

Where $(B_1(t),B_2(t))$ is two dimensional Brownian motion and $\alpha , \beta$ are constants.

Is there any hint how to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

According to the cited example 5.1.3 you got to consider the increments of the process
$$
Y_t=e^{-Jt}X_t
\ \text{ with }\ X=\pmatrix{X_1\\X_2},\ J=\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}.
$$

Comment: Would you please explain more?

Comment: You get $dY_t=e^{-Jt}A\,dB_t$, where $A$ is the diagonal matrix with $α,β$. The integral of that is the most explicit term you will get.

Comment: For future readers, there is a thorough explanation to a similar question in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1412919/536305